# What could be wrong with my friends Eclipse IDE the "Android SDK" button doesn't load the SDK window

Tags: java, android, eclipse, youtube, ide

Video of the problem.
http://youtu.be/Cbk6_-EEgak

Source of the eclipse version, this is a fresh install of eclipse from.  [android.com](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the SDK folder, then go to Tools and open android.bat, 
Let us know if that works.

Comment: http://screencloud.net/v/ifK3 I'm going to go with no.
A better image http://screencloud.net/v/5BOW